# Create forum in Moodle via external PHP

Tags: php, forum, moodle, creation

I would like to create a forum into a Moodle course (specified by the user) **using PHP**.

I've tried to search it for the net but I haven't found nothing, even in Moodle webservices (in which I cannot find a function to create a forum).

**The idea is the user to choose a course** (one in which he/she'll be studying), select a "unit",  insert a **title and the content**, **and submit it** (the rest of the options can be the default ones).

I can retrieve all the data I want from Database but **I cannot create any forum**. I've tried adding it **via SQL** too, but I haven't been able **neither**.

Hope someone here can help me!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you directly want to create a forum then you need to do following steps -

1. Insert new record into  **mdl_forum** table and get inserted id
2. Insert new record into **mdl_course_module** table with following values
   course=courseid,module=7(for forum, in moodle 2.9 the forum id is 9),instance=fourmid,visible=1,showavailability=1
3. Insert record if not exist or Update record into **mdl_course_section** with following values and get sectionid 
   course = courseid, visible = 1, sequence = moduleid(comma seprated),
4. Update **mdl_course_module** table and update sectionid

Finally rebuild moodle coures cache

Here is the moodle code to create a new fourm.

```
$forum = new stdClass();
$forum->course = $courseid;
$forum->type = "general";    
$forum->timemodified = time();
$forum->id = $DB->insert_record("forum", $forum);

if (! $module = $DB->get_record("modules", array("name" => "forum"))) {
    echo $OUTPUT->notification("Could not find forum module!!");
    return false;
}
$mod = new stdClass();
$mod->course = $courseid;
$mod->module = $module->id;
$mod->instance = $forum->id;
$mod->section = 0;
if (! $mod->coursemodule = add_course_module($mod) ) {   // assumes course/lib.php is loaded
    echo $OUTPUT->notification("Could not add a new course module to the course '" . $courseid . "'");
    return false;
}
if (! $sectionid = add_mod_to_section($mod) ) {   // assumes course/lib.php is loaded
    echo $OUTPUT->notification("Could not add the new course module to that section");
    return false;
}
$DB->set_field("course_modules", "section", $sectionid, array("id" => $mod->coursemodule));

include_once("$CFG->dirroot/course/lib.php");
rebuild_course_cache($courseid);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Let's see if it fits with my needs!

Comment: Could you help me with the tables to enrol a student into a course directly? I suppose mdl_enrol, mdl_user_enrolments, mdl_role_assignments and mdl_context, that last table I don't understand what kind of records contains. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have 50 points to comment, so the addendum for the excellent answer from Jitendra goes as an "answer". On Moodle 2.4 the add_mod_to_section() became deprecated, so it should be changed to:

```
$sectionid = course_add_cm_to_section ($courseid, $mod->coursemodule, $sectionid, null);
```